# Pivot selection for QuickSort , what is going , is something incorrect in my algo?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Can some one please guide me with my implementation of QuickSort. I am trying to visualize what is wrong with my implementation of quick sort , when I select the pivot as the last element in the array.

Below is my code :

```
    public void quickSort(int[] input, int left, int right) {
        if(left < right) {
            //int pivot = input[(left + right) / 2]; // works fine with this
            //int pivot = input[left];               // works fine with this
            int pivot = input[right];
            int index = partition(input, left, right, pivot); // line 12
            quickSort(input, left, index - 1); // line 13
            quickSort(input, index, right);    // line 14
        } 
    }
    
    private int partition(int[] input, int left, int right, int pivot) {
        while(left <= right) {
            while(input[left] < pivot) {
                left++;
            }
            while(input[right] > pivot) {
                right--;
            }
            if(left <= right) {
                int temp = input[left];
                input[left] = input[right];
                input[right] = temp;
                left++;
                right--;
            }
        }
        return left;
    }
```

If works fine when I select the pivot as

```
int pivot = input[(left + right) / 2]; // works with this
int pivot = input[left + (right - left) / 2]; // works with this
int pivot = input[left];               // works with this
```

When pivot is `input[right]`, it fails with the exception of

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.maverick.solution.Solution.quickSort(Solution.java:12)
    at com.maverick.solution.Solution.quickSort(Solution.java:13)
```

Please guide me, in correcting the issue or what is going wrong.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The problem basically comes when the largest element reaches the end of the array. In that situation, `left` and `right` values will be equal and `partition()` will return `array.length+1` and same function call will be made again and again.

Example: `[5,4,3,2,1]`
If you debug the code, you will see that the problem starts when a `quickSort([1,4,3,2,5],1,4)` call happens. This calls `partition()` which returns 5 and in the next line again `quickSort([1,4,3,2,5],1,4)` happens, the cycle continues.

Probably a correction in logic is required for `partition()`, when both `left` and `right` values have become equal and when largest element is present at `right` position.

Think about the work of `partition()`, which basically is to return index till which array is sorted, is your logic for `partition()` achieving it?

Try different inputs and debug the code.

For more on quick sort, you can refer [this book](https://edutechlearners.com/download/Introduction_to_algorithms-3rd%20Edition.pdf)